# Laravel 5.2 Try Catch Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to run this code :

```
Route::group(["prefix" => "{user}", "middleware" => "web"], function () {
    Route::get("/", function (User $user) {
        try {
            return $user;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo "ads";
        }
    });
    Route::get("/photos", function (User $user) {
        return $user->albums;
    });
});
```

So in above code i am using Route Binding when user enter url like this : http://localhost:8000/myusername then it will show that user information but if user will not available i just want to catch exception so that is not working.

I am getting error :

[image]

What should be a issue ? Why try catch not working.

Comment: The `try` is working, you are returning `$user`, and `$user` is defined in your url (actually, it's equal to **myusername**, even if it don't exist in your database)
You need to make a request, using your User model to try catching the user, and if that request return false, trown an error.

Comment: Looks like the error is happening before the code you've posted.

Comment: Yes in try i saw code is working.

Comment: But i want to attach user with username on url, i saw this option as Route Binding.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fetch that user in your controller, and return a redirect if it can't be found. Or leave the default functionality and let laravel throw a 404 if the user can't be found.  `try / catch` in routes feels wrong on so many levels...

Answer (score 1):

The way you are trying will not work. You have to `bind`, to show Laravel how to query by name, instead of ID.

Add this before your `Route::group`:

```
Route::bind('user', function($value)
{
    return User::where('name', $value)->first();
});
```

You can remove your try/catch. If you want to check if your model has been found, just use like this:

```
Route::get("/", function ($id) {
    try {
        return User::findOrFail($id);
    } catch(ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        echo "ads"
    }
});
```